# How to get DIV ID on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript and couldnt find answer online (I feel like its out there since this seems pretty simple thing, I might not be using the right search terms though)

I am working with the code in this jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ApoG/f7qqq6k2/4/

```
$('.item').click(function(){

    if( document.getElementById("one").style.display != "none") {
        document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block";}

    var $this = $(this),
    tileStyle = $this.hasClass('big') ? { width: 50, height: 50} : { width: 170, height: 110};
    $this.toggleClass('big');

    $this.find('.item-content').stop().animate( tileStyle );

    $container.isotope( 'reLayout' )

});
```

When you click a div, it takes the 'item' class and changes its properties.

My goal is to have image or one type of text in a widget when its small and another text or image when its expanded on click. I am going to achieve that by changing div custom properties when its clicked using an if statement in my javascript. (right now testing with changes to display)

My questions is...since 'item' class is selected on click, how can I get the DIV ID on click? (right now I hard coded div id)

Thank you.

Comment: Which `div` `id` you need to find?

Comment: Why don't you use `$("#one").toggle()` instead of all that raw Javascript?

Comment: I need to be able to find all of them on click. So the size of container changes on click...I want one type of content to show up when its closed, and another type of content to show up when it opens up. 

I will try the .toggle()...not familiar with that functionality, thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the toggle tip. I used that to make my code work and show different things in the box depending on the click of the div.

Here is what I ended up doing:

https://jsfiddle.net/ApoG/z3x6hqLe/

```
<script>
function toggleText1() {
$('#one_one').toggle();
$('#one_two').toggle();
} 
function toggleText2() {
$('#two_one').toggle();
$('#two_two').toggle();
 } 

</script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div id=one style=display:"none" class="item-content" onclick="toggleText1()"> 
     <div id=one_one class="text" >Show More</div>
     <div id=one_two class="text" style="display:none">Show Less</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div id=two style=display:"none" class="item-content" onclick="toggleText2()">
     <div id=two_one class="text" >Show More</div>
     <div id=two_two class="text" style="display:none">Show Less</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div id=three style=display:"none" class="item-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am definitely sure there is a more optimal way to define all the toggle but as I mentioned earlier I am a complete newb so hopefully with more tinkering I will figure that one out.

Answer (score 4):

With JQuery:

```
  $('div').click(function(){
  alert(this.id);
  });
```

[JSFiddle Demo, with your full code](https://jsfiddle.net/y0y1hovp/)
With Pure JS:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
for(var i=0; i<div.length; i++){ 
 div[i].onclick = function(){ 
   alert(this.id); 
 } 
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lby4jac/)

Comment: This is good, but the problem is that your code makes the other expand function not work (the one that references the class "item"...I need to get ID while also executing the expand/collapse of the widget...

I tried using your code to declare a global variable that could be passed into the other click function but so far unsuccessful.